# Animation lag when going from one fragment to another on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been browsing for a couple days before asking but can't find anything to completely answer my question. I have two fragments inside of a frame. When I switch from one fragment to another it is lagging when there is another fragment in the frame. I have tried to hide while transitions but it does not look good.

MainActivity (Frame):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    HomePage homeFrag = new HomePage(); //create game fragment
    ft.add(R.id.activity_main, homeFrag, "Home");
    ft.show(homeFrag);
    ft.commit();
```

Fragment 1:

```
startNewGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //ft.hide(frag);
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_right,  R.anim.exit_to_left);
                    ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, new PlayGame(), "PlayGame");
                    ft.addToBackStack("Home");
                    ft.commit();
                }
            };
            thread.run();

        }
    });
```

Fragment 2:

```
public android.view.View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_game, container, false);
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(keyEvent.getKeyCode() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                return true;
            } else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you using a slow pc to run your emulator? and testing it on an emulator? or low memory device, that's likely the problems

Comment: I have a GTX970 but I will try to beef up a new emulator and try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user7568042, the problem was simply the emulator settings were not high enough. The low settings was making the emulator show fps lag rather than a code issue. The remedy was to increase settings and restart the emulator.